# Why does this function break my form functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out why this function does not work when written a certain way but works if I break up the function.

I initially hide sections of a form, and then want to show or hide based on a radio check. These are two different forms on separate pages so I'm wondering if that has something to do with it now working written the first way?

jQuery:

```
$formMailSelected.hide();
$formEmailSelected.hide();
$formPhoneSelected.hide();
$formEmailSelectedRepresentative.hide();
```

When written like this it does not work:

```
  $('input:radio[name="howToContact"]').change(function () {
  if (this.checked) {
    if (this.value === 'Phone' || 'Mail') {

      $formPhoneSelected.fadeIn(750);
      $formEmailSelectedRepresentative.hide();

      $formMailSelected.fadeIn(750);
      $formEmailSelected.hide();

    } else if (this.value === 'Email') {

      $formEmailSelectedRepresentative.fadeIn(750);
      $formPhoneSelected.hide();

      $formMailSelected.hide();
      $formEmailSelected.fadeIn(750);
    }
  }
});
```

Broken up and written like this, it DOES work as I would like:

```
  $('input:radio[name="howToContact"]').change(function () {
  if (this.checked) {
    if (this.value === 'Mail') {

      $formMailSelected.fadeIn(750);
      $formEmailSelected.hide();

    } else if (this.value === 'Email') {

      $formMailSelected.hide();
      $formEmailSelected.fadeIn(750);

    }
  }
});


$('input:radio[name="howToContact"]').change(function () {
  if (this.checked) {
    if (this.value === 'Phone') {

      $formPhoneSelected.fadeIn(750);
      $formEmailSelectedRepresentative.hide();

    } else if (this.value === 'Email') {

      $formPhoneSelected.hide();
      $formEmailSelectedRepresentative.fadeIn(750);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `this.value === 'Phone' || 'Mail'` is always truthy, you mean `this.value === 'Phone' || this.value === 'Mail'`

Comment: aaaa I see! :) thank you for the solution / tip